# Install SSH server using command line commands

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, ssh

There is a windows server with running HTTP and FTP server.

I have access to the command line because I've run HTTP server under administrator account, however it's much more comfortable to run the command line directly through SSH.

Is there any SSH server that can be easily installed and managed through command line commands?

Comment: The Windows SSH servers I've seen (freeSSHd and the proprietary Bitvise SSH) both have GUI configuration tools. You might be better off running OpenSSH in Cygwin if you want something you can manage without a GUI.

Comment: @user55325 your comment could be an answer. :)

Comment: @medigeek maybe, if I had ever tested it to make sure it actually works... :P

Comment: It also depends what you want as "command line". When you install OpenSSH you'll get access to a bash-prompt on the server. Not the normal "Command prompt" from Windows. You can access the complete drive (having root access) with `cd /cygdrive/c` but commands you type should be `bash`-commands. So i'm not sure if SSH is the way to go if you expect the 'normal' "command prompt".

Answer (score 1):

## Cygwin/OpenSSH

I achieved a fully automated installation of OpenSSH sshd using Cygwin. Cygwin supports non-interactive setup *without* apt-cyg. The `ssh-host-config` script can run without prompting any value (using `setup.exe` with `--quiet-mode` option, plus a lot of others). Additional configuration happens with generated text files and standard Cygwin commands (like setting file permissions). After that, sshd can run as a Windows Service so you can start/stop it using `net start/stop`.

Cygwin is the only solution I found to run an SSH server from a VirtualBox Guest set up by ievms, with setup fully automated using VBoxManage guestcontrol. It is open-source, free as free beer, and OpenSSH has an impressive set of features.

## Bitvise SSH Server

Bitvise SSH Server supports silent installation from the command line:

```
BvSshServer-Inst.exe -defaultInstance -acceptEULA -startService
```

When running the installer this way, it automatically selects the 30-day trial.

Bitvise SSH Server supports [scripted configuration](https://www.bitvise.com/wug-wcfg) by exposing COM objects. In more concrete terms, this allows to configure everything from a PowerShell script.

Unfortunately I couldn't make such configuration script run from a VirtualBox Host using `VBoxManage guestcontrol exec` but this looks like a Windows/VirtualBox issue.

## FreeSSHd

FreeSSHd seems to support [silent install with WPKG](https://wpkg.org/FreeSSHd). On Windows 7 the `/VERYSILENT /NOICON /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES` option set triggers an "Interactive Service Detection" that can be safely dismissed if you plan to reboot soon.

I didn't play a lot with FreeSSHd since lots of users in the forum complain about public key authentication support.